# How to use CoffeeScript specs with Jasmine-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, tdd, jasmine

I am running Rails 3.2.13 with Ruby version 2.0.0-p195.  I am using the Jasmine-Rails gem version 0.4.5 with the asset pipeline enabled.  I would like to write my specs in CoffeeScript but I have not been able to figure out how to name the file and configure the jasmine.yml such that the specs will be picked up and parsed properly.

Here is the contents of my jasmine.yml file:

```
src_dir: "app/assets/javascripts"

src_files:
 - "application.{js,coffee}"

spec_dir: spec/javascripts

helpers:
  - "helpers/**/*.{js,coffee}"

spec_files:
  - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js,coffee}"
```

I've tried naming the file my_spec.js.coffee. That doesn't work.  Of course the my_spec.js naming convention works just fine.  I also tried messing with the spec_files value in jasmine.yml without any success.

Thanks in advance to anyone that has struggle with a similar issue, figured it out, and can help me along the path of writing slightly less tedious specs.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Jasmine-Rails's Github homepage](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-rails):

> The jasmine-rails gem fully supports the Rails asset pipeline which means you can:
>
> - **use coffee_script or other Javascript precompilers for source or test files**
> - use sprockets directives to control inclusion/exclusion of dependent files
> - leverage asset pipeline search paths to include assets from various sources/gems
>
> **If you choose to use the asset pipeline support, many of the `jasmine.yml` configurations become unnecessary** and you can rely on the Rails asset pipeline to do the hard work of controlling what files are included in your testsuite.

```yml
# minimalist jasmine.yml configuration when leveraging asset pipeline
spec_files:
  - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js,coffee}"
```

This defines the name pattern for the spec files. That is, zero or more characters, followed by `Spec` or `spec`, and with an `js` or `coffee` extension.

Add Jasmine-Rails routes configuration to `config/routes.rb`.

```
mount JasmineRails::Engine => "/specs" if defined?(JasmineRails)
```

Now you can write a spec to test Foo in spec/javascripts/my_spec.coffee.

```coffee
describe 'Foo', ->
  it 'does something', ->
    expect(1 + 1).toBe(2)
```

You RoR project structure should be partly like this:

```
RailsApp/
|---app/
|---config/
|   |---routes.rb
|---...
|---spec/
    |---javascripts/
        |---my_spec.coffee
        |---support/
            |---jasmine.yml
```

You can test the specs with:

```
bundle exec rake spec:javascript
```

Or you can start rails server and check the path for Jasmine-Rails (`/specs`).

Comment: Hmmm, it appears you did not read my question thoroughly.  I have it set up and working with javascript files as spec files.  I just cannot get it to work with CoffeeScript files.  The .coffee files are pulled in and throw an error(only with the .coffee extension other than that the file is identical to a working file with a .js extension) and the .js.coffee files are not pulled into the tests at all.

Comment: @RebekahWaterbury I know you want to write coffeescript specs, and what I have provided is the approach how I managed to write Jasmine specs in coffeescript. I've tested on my server and found that it accept and run the coffeescript specs happily.

Comment: Hmmm, that is the exact same set up that I have.  Maybe it's in my Gem setup.  I have gem 'coffee-rails' within the asset block of my Gemfile. Are you using that gem and/or grouping it in that location.  I am going to try moving it out to the non-grouped area. I'll see how that goes.

Comment: @RebekahWaterbury I'm using the default Gemfile and `coffee-rails` lies in `:assets` group.

Comment: Yes, I have found my error.  It is a conceptual issue as I have not worked with CoffeeScript very much before.  The spec was being pulled in, it just will not work together with the standard javascript.  I had the errant understanding that Javascript could be used in CoffeeScript files without any adjustment. I was wrong.  Thank you for your attention and helping me through this.  I will upvote your answer because it got me to the right place and assuming someone is using CoffeeScript correctly it will work for them ;)

Comment: ahhh.. and don't forget to include gem 'coffee-rails' if using coffee script! d'oh

Answer (score 2):

Just a little thing.  Your file naming convention uses two extensions: `my_spec.js.coffee`

The jasmine.yml file is expecting just "spec" followed by "coffee".  The two extensions are not matching this pattern.

```
spec_files:
  - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js,coffee}"
```

Aire Shaw's excellent answer used the filename `my_spec.coffee` which matches the expectation of the jasmine.yml file.

If you wish to use the filename form `my_spec.js.coffee` (as well as .js and .coffee), you can change the jasmine.yml file to:

```
spec_files:
  - "**/*[Ss]pec.{js,coffee,js.coffee}"
```

I use your file name convention for my coffeescript and this worked for me.